# Implementing reliable log

Tags: c#, .net, windows, io

I need to implement reliable log file. I wanna be sure, that data saved or not saved to disk (atomicity) in service method. Service should maintain high degree of parallelism. How to implement the most efficient way? Method `FileStream.Flush(true)` is very slow. Method `FileStream.Write` does not guarantee, that data saved to disk.

Comment: Nothing guarantees a  write to disk if your app dies or the power is pulled. Logging is a solved problem, so don't be wasting time writing your own, new logging library. Go for an existing package. I like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), but that would be a recommendation and that's not allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this thread looks like its turning into "library recommendation" advice and will attract opinionated answers.

Comment: @spender fine line, but asking for library recommendations is off-topic. Giving recommendations for which library to choose to solve a specific problem is just fine.

Comment: Simply use what's there already: [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx). It can be configured any way you like. And it can be dynamically enabled/disabled, so that you can take logs in a running system, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Dont reinvent the wheel. Use an existing, tried and trusted implementation such as Log4Net https://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi

Comment: Log4Net is trusted and it runs very good and has support. It just needs some time to get used to configure it, but its worth.